# Running Python from Command Propt - Unicode error

Tags: python

**Answered thank you**

Beginner here..I'm trying to run python from the command prompt. I think I have python correctly installed using Anaconda.

Trying to execute the file following code in command prompt:

```
"C:\Users\Alice\Documents\AliceCode.py"
```

This gives `unicode error in bites 2-3..`

If I run the code with `"C:/Users/Alice/Documents/AliceCode.py"` I do not get an output from the program. I just receive `'C:/Users/Alice/Documents/AliceCode.py'` as output.

Could someone please assist. Thank you!

Comment: You need an interpreter for running python scripts. A .py file is not an executable. Try ``python AliceCode.py`` if you have properly installed Python.

Comment: See `python.exe /?`

Comment: Got it working thanks guys

Used python AliceCode.py but had a few issues with the directory. Thanks